# Python append to label from multiple lists

Tags: python

So I have several lists that are the headers of variables in a data file. The setup looks like this:

> ```
> headerGroup1 = ["1", "2", "3, "4", "5"]
> headerGroup2 = ["6", "7", "8, "9", "10"]
> headerGroup3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
> ```

And I have a master file that looks like this:

> ```
> masterVars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
> ```

I want to do three things:

- Create a list that includes all the items from masterVars in order. And I don't know if values are unique.
- If a list item contained in headerGroupX is in the masterVars, prepend that header group to the list item.
- Dump a list that contains all 64k items into something I can manage in SPSS (sort of kidding about this one)

I think this would be simple if there were only 2 lists. The big problem I think I'm running into is what happens after you prepend data to a list item. But I'm not totally sure what I'm messing up.

EDITED:

Here is an example of what I would want to output:

> ```
> newMasterFile = ["headerGroup1, headerGroup3, 1", "headerGroup1, headerGroup3, 2", etc.]
> ```

Does this make anything clearer?

Comment: I ... don't understand.  Can you provide sample output?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You are trying to prepend a list(header group) to string(list item).

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? What is accomplished by having a string `"headerGroup1, headerGroup3, 1"` that has variable names in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import functools # python3 compatibility (for reduce function)

# unsorted - see 3,4 are swaped!
masterVars = ["1", "2", "4", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

input_dict=dict(headerGroup1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],headerGroup2 = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],headerGroup3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

# used builtins sorted function for sorting 
new_master_file=[' '.join(j[0])+' '+j[1] for j in [functools.reduce(lambda a,b:(i in input_dict[b] and a[0]+[b] or a[0],i),input_dict,[[],i]) for i in sorted(masterVars,key=int)]]

for i in new_master_file:
    print (i)
```

Or do you like more readable version? ;)

PS. What is SPSS?

Comment: I don't understand how this is working, but it is working. Perfectly. Thank you very very much. 

SPSS is Statistical Packages for the Social Sciences. It's a data analysis platform, and this is a data analysis problem. Sorry for being vague in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a list that includes all the items from masterVars in order.
>   And I don't know if values are unique.

Its already "sorted" (in quotes because you never explain what order you want), but assuming it wasn't:

```
>>> shuffle(masterVars)
>>> masterVars ['2', '9', '5', '7', '4', '1', '10', '6', '8', '3']
>>> sort(masterVars, key=lambda x: int(x))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

If you don't know if the values are unique, and you want them to be unique, convert it to a `set`.

> If a list item contained in headerGroupX is in the masterVars, prepend
>   that header group to the list item.

```
new_list = []
for i in headerGroupX:
   if i in masterVars:
      new_list.append(','.join(headerGroupX)+','+i)
   else:
      new_list.append(i)
```